# android studio update not running problem what can i do?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, updates

When I run it in android studio, it gives me such a problem. I updated it and it still doesn't work. What can I do?

6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

:app is currently compiled against android-32.

Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

:app is currently compiled against android-32.

Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

:app is currently compiled against android-32.

Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

:app is currently compiled against android-32.

Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

:app is currently compiled against android-32.

Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

:app is currently compiled against android-32.

Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

Comment: Try to change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 33 in app's build.gradle.

Comment: I checked but it didn't work, what else can I do?